# Can't load a subdomain of a website

Tags: dns, connection, timeout

I have a weird problem, http://docs.gitlab.com/ gives me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on chrome tested on several different browsers, ISPs (with mobile data and wifi), laptop, phones, ... all of them give me this error. (so can't be a firewall issue or anything).

also all gitlab.com | about.gitlab.com | ... load properly.

```bsh
nslookup docs.gitlab.com
Server:     1.0.0.1
Address:    1.0.0.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   docs.gitlab.com
Address: 35.185.44.232
```

```bsh
ping docs.gitlab.com
PING docs.gitlab.com (35.185.44.232): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 35.185.44.232: icmp_seq=0 ttl=101 time=234.375 ms
64 bytes from 35.185.44.232: icmp_seq=1 ttl=101 time=232.418 ms
64 bytes from 35.185.44.232: icmp_seq=2 ttl=101 time=233.903 ms
```

```bsh
curl docs.gitlab.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to docs.gitlab.com port 80: Operation timed out
```

---

Gerald in the comments section suggested that this could happen due to the fact that ipv6 is not supported on docs.gitlab.com, but github.com also doesn't have ipv6 supported, but loads fine for me.

https://ready.chair6.net/?url=docs.gitlab.com
https://ready.chair6.net/?url=github.com

---

From my server:

```bsh
traceroute -p 80 docs.gitlab.com   
traceroute to docs.gitlab.com (35.185.44.232), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  static.225.198.9.5.clients.your-server.de (5.9.198.225)  111.350 ms  106.862 ms  104.060 ms
 3  static.129.2.99.88.clients.your-server.de (88.99.2.129)  106.229 ms  105.674 ms  110.266 ms
 4  core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.141)  115.433 ms *
    core23.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.137)  108.444 ms
 5  core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  117.755 ms
    core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.229.77)  113.209 ms  110.851 ms
 6  142.250.160.234 (142.250.160.234)  109.509 ms  110.020 ms  113.523 ms
 7  232.44.185.35.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.185.44.232)  208.630 ms  206.959 ms  207.112 ms
```

From my home connection :

```bsh
traceroute -p 80 docs.gitlab.com
traceroute to docs.gitlab.com (35.185.44.232), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.068 ms  2.659 ms  5.253 ms
 2  5.238.26.1 (5.238.26.1)  14.396 ms  16.787 ms  21.767 ms
 3  10.51.242.73 (10.51.242.73)  41.912 ms  20.850 ms  18.791 ms
 4  10.51.242.74 (10.51.242.74)  26.811 ms  15.497 ms  17.607 ms
 5  10.202.7.19 (10.202.7.19)  20.166 ms  17.263 ms  20.668 ms
 6  10.202.7.18 (10.202.7.18)  17.967 ms  22.312 ms  16.737 ms
 7  10.201.47.186 (10.201.47.186)  25.609 ms  24.143 ms  32.804 ms
 8  et-10-0-6-0.ffttr6.frankfurt.opentransit.net (193.251.154.203)  105.352 ms
    85.132.90.157 (85.132.90.157)  100.037 ms
    85.132.90.169 (85.132.90.169)  101.856 ms
 9  72.14.214.52 (72.14.214.52)  136.799 ms
    193.251.252.246 (193.251.252.246)  137.395 ms *
10  72.14.212.229 (72.14.212.229)  164.663 ms  369.099 ms
    232.44.185.35.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.185.44.232)  391.888 ms
```

Comment: You should also add the information that was discovered in the comments on your [original question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1096174/cant-load-a-subdomain-of-a-website). It's not necessary that the users here start from scratch.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you updated

Comment: Why http not https? My browser automatically redirects to https on that link.

Comment: If you're on Linux/Unix, then post the output of `traceroute -T -p 80 docs.gitlab.com`.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your comment, for me it doesn't redirect also loading https://docs.gitlab.com doesn't make a difference

Comment: @Bib Thank you the comment, I updated the question and added the result of traceroute.

Comment: What about trying from your home connection? Hetzner is often blocked on Web Application Firewalls as a source of abuse traffic.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the response, I added the traceroute for my home connection, the same timeout happens on my chrome with my home connection.